# jquery accordion vs ajax accordion with data bind to data table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I build an ajax accordion that gets data from data table and inside the data table the user can perform actions and send data to the data base.
working with ajax is limiting and not very comfortable.
I thought about jquery because it looks nicer and as well as i know it can be more open to changes. can someone tell me if it is better to use jquery or ajax?
Thank to all

Comment: and what about using jquery with ajax?

Comment: I didn`t know that it is possible

Comment: for example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: i am using asp:accordion witch i thinking to replace